# GroupBy query with list of vertices

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Suppose I want to query the Neptune graph with "group-by" on one property (or more), and I want to get back the list of vertices too.

Let's say, I want to group-by on ("city", "age") and want to get the list of vertices too:

```
[
  {"city": "SFO", "age": 29, "persons": [v[1], ...]},
  {"city": "SFO", "age": 30, "persons": [v[10], v[13], ...]}, 
  ...
]
```

Or, get back the vertex with its properties (as `valueMap`):

```
[
  {"city": "SFO", "age": 29, "persons": [[id:1,label:person,name:[marko],age:[29],city:[SFO]], ...]},
  ...
]
```

AFAIK, Neptune doesn't support lambda nor variable assignments. is there a way to do this with one traversal and no lambdas?

**Update:** I'm able to get the vertices, but without their properties (with `valueMap`).

Query:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").group().
   by(values("city", "age").fold()).
   by(fold().
     match(__.as("p").unfold().values("city").as("city"),
           __.as("p").unfold().values("age").as("age"),
           __.as("p").fold().unfold().as("persons")).
     select("city", "age", "persons")).
   select(values).
   next()
```

Output:

```
==>[city:SFO,age:29,persons:[v[1]]]
==>[city:SFO,age:27,persons:[v[2],v[23]]]
...
```

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe I'm missing something, but right now I don't see where/why you would use a lambda at all

Comment: I've update the question with my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, then ...

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").
  group().
    by(values("city", "age").fold())
```

... or ...

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").
  group().
    by(valueMap("city", "age").by(unfold()))
```

... already gives you what you need, it's just about reformating the result. To merge the maps in keys and values together, you can do something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").
  group().
    by(valueMap("city", "age").by(unfold())).
  unfold().
  map(union(select(keys), 
            project("persons").
              by(values)).
      unfold().
      group().
        by(keys).
        by(select(values)))
```

Executing this on the modern toy graph (`city` replaced with `name`) will yield the following result:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin>     g.V().hasLabel("person").
......1>       group().
......2>         by(valueMap("name", "age").by(unfold())).
......3>       unfold().
......4>       map(union(select(keys), 
......5>                 project("persons").
......6>                   by(values)).
......7>           unfold().
......8>           group().
......9>             by(keys).
.....10>             by(select(values)))
==>[persons:[v[2]],name:vadas,age:27]
==>[persons:[v[4]],name:josh,age:32]
==>[persons:[v[1]],name:marko,age:29]
==>[persons:[v[6]],name:peter,age:35]
```

Comment: You are right. I'm reformatting the output because I'm not able to represent the original group-by traversal as a valid JSON (map keys are list type). Thanks for your help.